# Definitive list of GATT services detectable in iOS Settings app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a BLE Peripheral app implemented, and have added a Heart Rate service as per the Bluetooth SIG, 0x180D UUID from memory.

[The BT services link](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx)

On another iOS device, this peripheral is instantly visible in the Settings app under Bluetooth "OTHER DEVICES" when advertising is started.

If I then remove the Heart Rate Service and just have my custom service, the device is not visible in the Settings app. 
All as expected.

Question - is there a definitive list of what does and doesn't appear in the Settings app ? Or do all the GATT Services appear ?

Comment: No GATT service devices should appear in bluetooth settings unless an app has a connection to it.

Comment: OK, and iOS 8 now has HealthKit hence Heart Rate GATT service appears in Settings app.

Comment: That is only on iPhone, not on iPad